# Vega How to SUM all descendants value of every node on a treemap

Tags: vega

I am trying to access the sum of values for a node in VEGA. In other words, I want to display sum of "percentage" values of all leaves for each parent node.

Got the following Vega specs (https://gist.github.com/omerakko/655674f9f37e9361fe5378b6d440e411)

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "An example of treemap layout for hierarchical data.",
  "width": 960,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 2.5,
  "autosize": "none",

 

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "tree",
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omerakko/VEGA/main/vegaTreemapData.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stratify",
          "key": "id",
          "parentKey": "parent"
        },
        {
          "type": "treemap",
          "field": "percentage",
          "sort": {"field": "value", "order":"descending"},
          "round": true,
          "method": "resquarify",
          "ratio": 1,
          "size": [{"signal": "width"}, {"signal": "height"}],
          "paddingOuter": 2,
          "paddingInner":2

          
          
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [{ "type": "filter", "expr": "datum.children" }]
      
    },
     
      
    
    {
      "name": "leaves",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [{ "type": "filter", "expr": "!datum.children" },
      {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.percentage > 0"}]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "nodes", "field": "name"},
      "range": [
        "transparent", "#dd96ba", "#dea84e", "#c83836", "#dfde9b",
        "#5eafb9", "#adc35d"]
    },
    {
      "name": "size",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": [0, 1, 2, 3],
      "range": [256, 28, 20, 14]
    },
    {
      "name": "opacity",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": [0, 1, 2, 3],
      "range": [0.15, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0]
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
         "fill": {"value":"#333238"},
          "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"},
          "strokeWidth":{"value": 5}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x0"},
          "y": {"field": "y0"},
          "x2": {"field": "x1"},
          "y2": {"field": "y1"},
          "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "leaves"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#fff"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x0"},
          "y": {"field": "y0"},
          "x2": {"field": "x1"},
          "y2": {"field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"value": "transparent"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "font": {"value": "Helvetica Neue, Arial"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"},
          "text": {"field": "name"},
          "fontSize": {"scale": "size", "field": "depth"}
          
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "0.5 * (datum.x0 + datum.x1)"},
          "y": {"signal": "0.5 * (datum.y0 + datum.y1)"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There is doc available https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/treemap/ here saying that I can access to what I want, but I couldnt manage to apply it to the specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's not currently possible in Vega. There's [this PR](https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/1900) that hasn't been merged yet.

But you can work around that by manually aggregating the values and then looking them up. Here a [gist](https://gist.github.com/roveo/a8b6f1920339475e537d4ca03a0c896c) in which there's now a `total` field for each node, the relevant part being:

```json
{
  "name": "leaves",
  "source": "tree",
  "transform": [
    {"type": "filter", "expr": "!datum.children"},
    {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.percentage > 0.3"}
  ]
},
{
  "name": "totals",
  "source": "leaves",
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "aggregate",
      "groupby": ["parent"],
      "fields": ["percentage"],
      "as": ["total"],
      "ops": ["sum"]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "nodes",
  "source": "tree",
  "transform": [
    {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.children"},
    {
      "type": "lookup",
      "from": "totals",
      "key": "parent",
      "fields": ["id"],
      "values": ["total"],
      "as": ["total"]
    }
  ]
},
```

Basically you just get sums of all the leaves by parent in `totals` and then, after constructing the base `nodes` dataset, look the total up in `totals`.

Note that this will only work for this particular example, where there are exactly two levels in the hierarchy.